# One word for "does not believe"

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

What is a word meaning *does not believe*?

The word will be used in this sentence, where I am looking for just one word to replace the three words *does not believe* which otherwise fit in this sentence.

> She _______ in dreams.

However, the exact sentence structure shown above ᴄᴀɴ be modified if another structure meaning the same thing lends itself to a better-sounding solution.

Comment: Have you looked up to "disbelieve" in the dictionary? Can you tell us why you need one word for *does not believe* and why it can't be used?

Comment: First time I searched it on Google, it only showed "believe". I believe I did a typographical error.

Comment: @Rathony Ignore the post, ser. I found the word: shunned.

Comment: @Stannis, nice to know you found your word; but how does _shunned_ mean _does not believe_? Just curious!

Comment: Note that *does not believe* is definitely not the same as *does not believe in*.

Comment: Given that the OP mentioned _shun_ as a suitable word, I wonder if _ignores_ comes even closer as it also implies _does not believe in_ to some extent.

Comment: I was going to comment that the OP should define what he means by *does not believe* or *does not believe in*. — She doesn’t believe in the Easter Bunny (or ghosts, or whatever).  She doesn’t believe in putting off until tomorrow what she can do today.  She doesn’t believe in marriage (or capitalism, or whatever).  She doesn’t believe in herself. — Different meanings; different antonyms. But that ship of dreams seems to have sailed.  If the OP likes *shun*, then ***doubt*** and ***deny*** might fit.

Comment: *She is **skeptical** of dreams.*  (By the way *shun* doesn't work for me *at all*.)

Answer (score 1):

"She [distrusts](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/distrust) dreams."

> Distrust: lack of trust or confidence. A feeling that someone or something is not honest and cannot be trusted.

(Merriam-Webster)

'[Rejects](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reject)' would be a good answer, but it does not fit the sentence.

> Reject: to refuse to believe, accept, or consider (something).

(Merriam-Webster)

Answer (score 0):

**incredulous** is the word I would use for someone who is not willing to believe. I believe in other context it can be used for one who does not believe.

Comment: Can you explain how the word *incredulous* could be used in "She does not believe in dreams?"

Comment: I missed out on the sentence for it to be used in. Sorry for that.

Comment: You don't have to say sorry to me. Welcome to English Language and Usage. Please visit the Help Center and read the guidelines to understand  how this site works, especially this one, http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Given the context of the use.... she is a disbeliever of dreams.